# How do I set `SO_RCVTIMEO` on a socket in Perl?

Tags: perl, sockets, setsockopt, io-socket

If I try like this:

```
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new( … )                    or die "no socket for you";
defined $sock->setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, 30)   or die "setsockopt: $!";
```

then my script suffers death from "setsockopt: Invalid argument at [line 2]". The `IO::Socket` and `perlfunc` pods do not say, though perlfunc gives an example with `TCP_NODELAY` which makes it look like the above should work.

(**quick note:** I've answered my own question, as best I can, but certainly welcome a better answer. The most obvious "better" would be for it to be portable, at least on POSIX machines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `strace` on the Perl interpreter running the script, it becomes clear that the problem is that Perl isn't packing a `struct timeval` (required by `SO_RCVTIMEO`) for you. Further, there do not appear to be helper functions to do it for you. Instead, you must do it yourself.

This turns out to be problematic because `struct timeval` is machine-specific. The Single Unix Specification [defines it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_time.h.html):

> The <sys/time.h> header shall define the timeval structure, which
> shall include at least the following members:
>
> ```
> time_t         tv_sec        Seconds.
> suseconds_t    tv_usec       Microseconds.
> ```

It also says that `time_t` is an integer or real-floating type, and "`suseconds_t` shall be a signed integer type capable of storing values at least in the range [-1, 1000000]" (see [sys/types.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html)).

Without access to the C structure, it isn't possible to do this portably. But if we assume glibc, that has a more restrictive definition, specifying both as `long`, and that they're the only two members. However, [this is a documentation bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=155100). So never mind.

So, the best I can do, which I believe works on both GNU/Linux IA-32 and GNU/Linux AMD64, is this:

```
$sock->setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, pack('l!l!', 30, 0))
    or die "setsockopt: $!";
```

The `pack` format `l!` means to use the current machine's native `long`—which is what the glibc docs say, and is apparently implemented for at least some glibc architectures (but not SPARC, according to the bug).

Comment: IO::Socket::Timeout seems to be the answer you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Does `$myiosockinet->timeout( 30 );` or `$myiosockinet->timeout( 30 * 1000000 );` work?

If it doesn't, that module (`IO::Socket::INET` or `Socket`) needs an update :) because http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/pod/perlfaq8.pod#Where_do_I_get_the_include_files_to_do_ioctl%28%29_or_syscall%28%29%3F is unsatisfying

Comment: No, I tried that (or at least, I tried the option in the constructor). From strace, setting timeout appears to be a no-op. If you look at the module code, it just sets a member variable, which is apparently only used by connect and accept.

Comment: The option in the constructor just does not work, because the code would do anything in response to it has been commented out, seemingly since it was committed in 1998: https://github.com/perl/perl5/commit/cf7fe8a#diff-a365bb9ac2a017254a49ce6d296fcd040633f84ae66f21783706a70006ebc74eR172.
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570440/perl-how-to-get-iosocketinet-timeout-after-x-seconds/3570601