# Not able to timeout

Tags: perl

I am using the following code. I want to timeout and close the connection after 20 seconds, tried with alarms but nothing worked. Here is my code:

```
my $socket_resp = IO::Socket::INET->new(Blocking => 0, LocalPort => $comm_port, Proto => 'udp', Timeout => 2);
    $socket_resp->setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO, SO_RCVTIMEO, 10);
    print "Waiting for Response On Port $comm_port\n";
    while (my $recieved_data = $socket_resp->getline()) {
        chomp($recieved_data);
        print "$recieved_data\n";
        if ($recieved_data =~ m/^done/i) {
            last;
        }
    }

    $socket_resp->close();
```

Comment: Did you try: [How to get IO::Socket::INET timeout after X seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570440/perl-how-to-get-iosocketinet-timeout-after-x-seconds)

Comment: Do you want a total socket lifespan of at most 20 seconds, or a patience of 20 seconds for *each* `getline()` call?

Comment: You might want to [go back trough your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1065000/user1065000?tab=questions) and [accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) that have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your entire read loop in an alarm, as suggested in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3570440/132382) will very likely do what you want.  You don't show us code, so we don't know why your previous attempts failed.

That said, SO_RCVTIMEO can be made to work, too, albeit a bit differently.

You want a *blocking* rather than non-blocking socket in this case.  You also want to `setsockopt` correctly, which requires SOL_SOCKET and `pack()`ing a [`struct timeval`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/setsockopt.html):

```
my $s = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto => 'udp', ...);            # N.B.: blocking
$s->setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, pack('l!l!', 20, 0));  # N.B.: pack()
while (<$s>) {
  ...
}
```

Now, the above waits 20 seconds for each underlying call to `read()`, which may be more than the number of *lines* returned to your application.  That is, if I send your application `"foo\n"` in one datagram and then nothing, you'll timeout after 20 seconds.  However, I might send `"f"`, then wait 19 seconds, `"o"`, then wait 19 seconds, `"o"`, then wait 19 seconds, ... you get the idea.)