# Make blocking timeout IO::Socket read

Tags: perl, sockets

I need to make blocking socket read end by timeout. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570440/perl-how-to-get-iosocketinet-timeout-after-x-seconds) question, I learned that IO::Socket::INET doesn't pay attention to Timeout option and learned about solution using `eval`/`alarm`. But I'm working on Windows and `alarm` doesn't work properly. Is there any other solution?

Comment: How are you using sockets on Windows?

Comment: The `timeout` option is about establishing a socket connection, not reading data from a connection that is already established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to reading from the socket, use the [4-argument version of `select`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#select), with the desired timeout, to test whether any data is available on the socket to be read.

Also see the [`IO::Select`](http://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aSelect) module, and specifically the `IO::Select::can_read($timeout)` method to test if a socket read will block or not.

Example:

```
$read_timeout = 5.0; # seconds
$socket = IO::Socket->new( ... );     # socket to read from

$selector = IO::Select->new;
$selector->add( $socket );

...

@ready = $selector->can_read( $read_timeout );
if (@ready > 0) {
    $socket->read( $buffer, 128 );   # copy 128 bytes into $buffer
} else {
    warn "data not available on socket now";
}
```

Comment: while this code might work, it should be using sysread, or otherwise select might not be triggered if for example the socket has some data on the fly.